# How to find this strange sum?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

$$ x= \frac{{(\underbrace{111...1}_{\text{no. of 1's = n}})}^2}{10^{n-1}} \\ 
y = (\underbrace{111...1}_{\text{no. of 1's = n}})^2 (mod \ 10^n) \\ 
S=\lfloor x \rfloor +y $$

Find a formula for any general value of $n$.

Comment: Hint $1111...1=9999...9/9=(10^n-1)/9$

Comment: Value of $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ so answer will be $y+1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets deal with $y=(11111....111)^2 (1's  :n \space times) \mod 10^n$ which can be rewritten as $y = (\frac{10^n-1}{9})^2 \mod 10^n$ which can be reduced to 
$y=(10^n-1)^2 * \frac{1}{81} \mod 10^n$ , now its obvious that $(10^n-1)^2 = 1\mod 10^n$ so actually $y= inverse \space  of \space 81 \mod 10^n$.

as an example : for $n=4$ then $y = \frac{1}{81} \mod 10^4 = 4321$ you can find the value of $y$ using the command $PowerMod[81,-1,10^n]$ for any $n$ in Wolfram Alpha.

secondly, dealing with $x$ which is a little bit trickier than $y$, we want to find the value of $\lfloor \frac{(\frac{10^n-1}{9})^2 }{10^{n-1}} \rfloor$ expanding the square and doing some basic arithmetic we arrive at $\lfloor \frac{10^{2n}-2*10^n+1}{81*10^{n-1}} \rfloor$ ,since $10^{2n}-2*10^{n}$ and $81*10^{n-1}$ both even numbers so the $1$ will not effect the floor value because it cant elevate the expression to the nearest upper integer. so we get rid of it and divide by $10^{n-1}$, now we are left with $\lfloor \frac{10^{n+1}-2*10^1}{81} \rfloor$  and because $\phi(81)=54$ where $\phi(x)$ is the Euler totient function which means that the $10^n$ is 54-cycle(period) mod 81. (actually its just 9).

i will list here all the remainder of division of $10^{n+1}$ over $81$.

n=0 => 10 mod 81

n=1 => 19 mod 81

n=2 => 28 mod 81

n=3 => 37 mod 81

n=4 => 46 mod 81

n=5 => 55 mod 81

n=6 => 64 mod 81

n=7 => 73 mod 81

n=8 => 1 mod 81

now for the remainder that are less than $20$ we will subtract $1$ from the final answer because of the floor function.

also there is a pattern which is $ 9 n+10 \mod 81$

so $\lfloor x \rfloor  = \frac{10^{n+1}-(9 n+10) \mod 81}{81} + (-1 \space if \space n = 0,1,8 \mod 9)$

the final touch is we calculate $S$ for any given $n$ which will be as follow :

$S_n = \frac{1}{81} \mod 10^n +   \frac{10^{n+1}-(9 n+10) \mod 81}{81} + (-1 \space if \space n = 0,1,8 \mod 9)$

note : $(-1 \space if \space n = 0,1,8 \mod 9)$ this means that from the value of $S_n$ we will subtract $1$ if $n$ is $0$ or $1$ or $8$ modulo $9$.

i hope that this answer is what you are looking for.